# Where/how to ask for opinions on site design?

Tags: discussion, design

I would like to know if I/users can post questions on SO about the design of their web-site/applications.

I would like some advice on the structure and layout of my site, things like "should I move that column to the left or remove it", "should I use a modal box for the about page or should I create a new page for it".

Kindly let me know if I am free to post this types of questions, or whether it is against community guidelines, and if so where *can* you go to get advice/opinions on the design of your website?

Comment: UX maybe? Not SO for sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know any site in the SE network where you can get reviews and opinions about your site's deisgn. AFAIK there's only CodeReview.SE, but obviously they review *code*, not *design*. I think you'll have to look outside the SE network to get a "design reviewed".

That being said, if you have practical design problems and can formulate specific questions about them, you *might* be able to get some help on these sister sites:

- UX.SE for questions about user interface design:

  > If you have a question about...
  >
  > Specific UX design problems UX issues that can be solved with expert
  >   advice or existing research Questions about HCI and user research …
  >   then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

  See [their "on topic" article](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more info.
- GraphicDesign.SE, which does include topics like:

  > Web design as related to look and feel, not coding.

  ...but be sure to check [their *extensive* "on topic" article](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

The main thing with almost all SE sites is that they typically require questions that are useful to a broader audience than just one person. This means you'll often have to first translate your *specific* question into a more widely applicable one, create an example scenario for it, ask the question, and apply the answers again to your specific situation.